# CSS and parallax issue for scrolling images

Tags: html, css, parallax, vertical-scrolling

I've attempted to modify a template that was using parallax w/ for scrolling and having some behind the page background images, but have an error either in the CSS or parallax that I can't seem to figure out.

If you go here http://3d-imagery.com/new/ and scroll down, you'll see a big white gap in the 2nd image at the top and bottom of it. I can't find the proper css change to get those gaps to close or changes in parallax JS. I have all the other images working fine, except that one. Am needing a second par of eyes to help :(

Comment: There's a couple of `<br />` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be a CSS issue. You have two line breaks `<br>` after `<!-- end services -->`

[image]

Removing them removes the white space.

[image]

Comment: You are my hero. I love you bro.